# Non-component onclick trigger React Component update

Tags: reactjs

If I have some buttons which were not React components, e.g. for an add to basket:

```
<button value="1">Buy Product 1</button>
<button value="2">Buy Product 2</button>
<button value="3">Buy Product 3</button>
```

And I have a React component that stores the values of buttons clicked (e.g. a basket view), how would I get the data from the buttons clicked into the react component? Would an event listener like this for each button suffice?: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html) I'm trying to do this all client side, as the buttons wil be rendered server side on pageload.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
In response to a suggestion below, here's a bit more background information:

The issue is that the buttons are generated in PHP and aren't repeated one after the other. We have a pre-existing system of twig template'd product listings, so the only real solution is to keep the buttons rendered as is, and use a react component for the basket view. So a click of a pre-existing non-react button needs to pass the value (product sku/id) into the react component to update the basket

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      basket: []
    }
    this.addItemToBasket = this.addItemToBasket.bind(this);
  }

  addItemToBasket(e) {
    let item = e.value;
    let basket = this.state.basket;
    basket.push(item);
    this.setState({basket: basket});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <button value="1" onClick={this.addItemToBasket(this)}>Buy Product 1</button>
      <button value="2" onClick={this.addItemToBasket(this)}>Buy Product 2</button>
      <button value="3" onClick={this.addItemToBasket(this)}>Buy Product 3</button>
     <Basket items={this.state.basket} />
    }
  }
}
```

this will call addItemToBasket when each button is clicked and then add that item to the basket and set the state with the new basket. Then you can pass the state as a prop to the component where you want to display what is added.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue is, and it's my fault for not explaining it clearer (I was trying to simplify it), is that the buttons are generated in PHP and aren't repeated one after the other. We have a pre-existing system of twig template'd product listings, so the only real solution is to keep the buttons rendered as is, and use a react component for the basket view. So a click of a pre-existing non-react button needs to pass the value (product sku/id) into the react component to update the basket